# Time counting over midnight

Tags: excel, vba, time, counting

Counting time over midnight fails

Counting time over midnight fails
I have made a code with two counters  - one (CountUPS) that counts seconds from 0 every time I start the program (A1) and one(CountUP) that counts seconds from a preset time (A2).
It works fine while it counts within the same day, but it gets a bug  every time it shall count over midnight. It stops when A2 reach 23:37:53 in time.
Is something wrong in my definition of values?

```
Sub RunMe()

Dim StartS As Single
Dim CellS As Range
Dim Cellt As Range
Dim CountUPS As Date
Dim CountUp As Date

'Timer is the number of seconds since midnight.
'Store timer at this point in a variable
StartS = Timer

'Store A1 in a variable to make it easier to refer
'to it later. Also, if the cell changes, you only
'have to change it in one place
Set CellS = Sheet1.Range("A1")

'This is the starting value.
CountUPS = TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)

'Set our cell to the starting value
CellS.Value = CountUPS

Set Cellt = Sheet1.Range("A2")
CountUp = Sheet1.Range("A2")

b_pause = True

Do While CellS.Value >= 0

    CellS.Value = CountUPS + TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - StartS + (StartS > Timer))
    Cellt.Value = CountUp + TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - StartS + (StartS > Timer))
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `CellS`is not a good name for a variable, because it already has a meaning in Excel (it is the range of all cells in the active worksheet). `(StartS > Timer)` evaluate to `True` or `False`, that are changed to `-1` or `0`, so you are only subtracting one second when the test is True. Finally, the parameters for TimeSerial second is Variant(Interger), so the maximal value is 32767 seconds

Comment: Aside from @VincentG accurate comments, what does ***gets a bug*** mean? Does everything freeze at that time?  What is in A2? Are there any error messages?  In general, and for future reference, that kind of information can be quite helpful in figuring out the problem.

Comment: Thanks @VincentG. A later test showed me the problem while I got an Erro 6 - overflow after appx. 9 hours of running. I tryed to change SINGLE to LONG for StartS, but it diddent help. Do you have any idea how to fix the limite

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld for guiding me. I'm new int this field. It stops right at 23:59:59 even though I try toe uses (Starts > Timer) to add one day. It stops at: CellS.Value = CountUPS + TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - StartS + (StartS > Timer)). A2 is used for a preset time that the counter starts to count from, and it is A2 that gives med problems when it reach midnight. A1 is always countion up from 0.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  When I use your code as you show it (commenting out the `b_pause=` line since you never declare, nor use, that variable), and enter a start time in A2, it does NOT stop at 23:59:59.  What are you not telling us?

Comment: Of course, your other problem with overflow is different, and due to the time arguments being limited to integers. And there is a solution for that, but let's figure out what's going on with your stopping problem.

Comment: Yes you are right @RonRosenfeld. If I simulate a midnight situation in daytime, with typing in 23:59:55 at cell A2, it will continue counting time. But If I stay up until midnight and watch the counter, it stops right after 23:59:59. I tryed it again last Friday. And then it gives me a Debug in the counter  algoritme.

Comment: And is there any error associated with the Debug? If so, can you tell us what it is? And exactly what line it is on?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When it reach midnight I get **Run-time error 6 - Overflow** and it fails at line: `Cellt.Value = CountUP + TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - StartS + (Starts > Timer ))`. But it shouldn’t have used the limited of 32767 seconds while it has only counted for appx 2 hours. If I restart the code it gets me another error: **Run-time error 1004 – Application-defined or object-defined error**. It fails in the line: `Cells.Value = CountUPS + TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer – StartS + (StartS>Timer))` in the loop. When I restarts from ties two debugs, it will count over midnight with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages clear up a lot of issues.

- The `overflow` error, as has been pointed out, is because of the integer constraints on the `TimeSerial` function arguments.
- The `1004` error, occurring at midnight, is because, when `Timer` reverts to `0` at midnight, your expression for seconds is a negative number.  Unless you are using the 1904 date system, you cannot express negative times in Excel.
- In trying to adjust for "passing midnight" you are conflating seconds and days, and Excel and VBA.  You are, in your macro, trying to add one second, whereas you probably really want to add one day.  Also, since `True` in VBA equates to `-1`, you are actually subtracting instead of adding anyway!

I think the following modifications may work, but have not tested them extensively. `86400` is the number of seconds in a day.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RunMe()

Dim StartS As Single
Dim CellS As Range
Dim Cellt As Range
Dim CountUPS As Date
Dim CountUp As Date

'Timer is the number of seconds since midnight.
'Store timer at this point in a variable
StartS = TIMER

'Store A1 in a variable to make it easier to refer
'to it later. Also, if the cell changes, you only
'have to change it in one place
Set CellS = Sheet1.Range("A1")

'This is the starting value.
CountUPS = TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)

'Set our cell to the starting value
CellS.Value = CountUPS

Set Cellt = Sheet1.Range("A2")
CountUp = Sheet1.Range("A2")

'b_pause = True

Do While CellS.Value >= 0

    CellS.Value = CountUPS + (TIMER - StartS - 86400 * (StartS > TIMER)) / 86400
    Cellt.Value = CountUp + (TIMER - StartS - 86400 * (StartS > TIMER)) / 86400
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to use the same code but changed one of the two counters to a count down timer form a preset time. But with the math in your code it gives me an Error when it research Zero. (I asume that it will try to * 0 ). The additional code looks like this. `Dim CountDown As Date` _`CountDown = TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)    'Set takttime`   _  `Cell.Value = CountDown - (Timer - Start - 86400 * (Start > Timer)) / 86400` Do you have an idear how to solve the problem.

Comment: @MMO No, not with the information you have provided. I suggest you post this problem as a new question, but first, please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and formulate your question accordingly, so the respondents do not have to ask multiple other questions in order to clarify the problem.