# Countdown Timer fails

Tags: excel, vba, countdowntimer

I have used this code with succes as a Count Up Timer, but **it fails** as a **Count Down Timer**. I get the

> Error 1004 Application-definde og object-defined error

in the line

```
Cell.Value = CountDown - (Timer - Start - 86400 * (Start > Timer)) / 86400
```

I think it multplies with zero.

I know the code will work with `Cell.Value = CountDown - TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - Start)`, but I can not use it, while `TimeSerial` is a Variant(integer) which means that the code can only do 32767 counts in seconds before it will stop in an **Overflow error**. 
Does anyone have an idear how to work around the error 1004 problem in the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewTimer() 'Countdown timer
    Dim Start As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CountDown As Date

    Start = Timer

    Set Cell = Sheet1.Range("B1")    'This is the starting value.
    CountDown = TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)    'Set takttime
    Cell.Value = CountDown

    Do While Cell.Value > 0
        Cell.Value = CountDown - (Timer - Start - 86400 * (Start > Timer)) / 86400
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to with `(Start > Timer)` this will either result in `True` (which casts to `-1`) or `False` (which casts to `0`). Can you explain what your attempt is here please?

Comment: @Peh With the `(Start > Timer)` I will avoid the counter to fail over midnight.

Comment: Can you please explain how your timer should count? Your calculation is completely unclear. • Did you understand what I wrote in my first comment?

Comment: @PEH I'm new into this, and will link you to my previous question where the calculation is comming from [link]  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212631/time-counting-over-midnight/54307054#54307054   - Yes I understand the evaluation of `True` or `False` and it is used in the Count UP Timer to count over midnight in the link. I' m not shure if I need it in the calculation if the Count Down Timer will pass midnight.

Comment: Strange I cannot reproduce your issue. The code runs fine. Try to explicitly convert the boolean into a number using `CLng(Start > Timer)`. If this doesn't help then something else must be wrong. Do you have any Sub/Function called `Timer`? If so rename it!

Comment: I know it sounds strange and I just checked one more time. When I run the code it will often work, but after a number of runs(5-10) - the Error 1004 apperas when I start the code again. By **END**ing the code, it might run again or fails with error 1004. I can reproduce the problem. I do not have a Sub named `Timer`

Comment: Oh if I run it multiple times I got the same error now. Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650146/3219613) for an alternative timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have no idea why your code throws that error and only sometimes, try this alternative which is without that issue.

```
Sub OtherTimer()
    Dim UserInput As String
    UserInput = "00:00:10"

    Dim SecondsToRun As Long
    SecondsToRun = CDbl(TimeValue(UserInput)) * 24 * 60 * 60

    Dim TimerStart As Double
    TimerStart = Timer 'remember when timer starts

    Do
        Range("B1").Value = Format$((SecondsToRun - (Timer - TimerStart)) / 24 / 60 / 60, "hh:mm:ss")
        'count backwards from 01:15 format as hh:mm:ss and output in cell A1

        DoEvents
    Loop While TimerStart + SecondsToRun > Timer 'run until SecondsToRun are over
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using boolean in a loop use a variable that takes 1 or 0. That will eliminate the error.

```
Dim temp As Integer
# ...
Do While Cell.Value > 0
    If Start > Timer Then
        temp = 1
    Else
        temp = 0
    End If

    Cell.Value = CountDown - (Timer - Start - 86400 * temp) / 86400
    DoEvents
Loop
```

In order to avoid overflow error, you can change type of `CountDown` to double and instead of using TimeSerial function specify time in days. Some examples:

```
CountDown = 1 # 1 day
CountDown = 1/24 # 1 hour
CountDown = 1/24/60 # 1 minute
CountDown = 1/24/60/60 # 1 second
CountDown = 2/24 + 40/24/60/60 # 2 hours and 40 seconds
```